Symplectic cobordisms between disjoint union of two contact solid $3$-torus to one contact solid $3$-torus
I would like to find a symplectic cobordism $M$ between $(\mathbb{T}^3, \xi_0 := \mathrm{d}\theta +r^2 \mathrm{d}\phi) \sqcup (\mathbb{T}^3, \xi_0)$ and $(\mathbb{T}^3, \xi_0)$ which satisfies the following condition :
The edge boundary is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1_\theta \times P$ where $P$ is a pair-of-pants.
If it's impossible, what is the possible obstruction?
I would like to know this is possible. What should be the good starting point? I've not read Eliashberg's papers about symplectic cobordisms, but I'd read Weinstein's symplectic handle before.

I don't understand your question. If you have a symplectic cobordism $M$ from $Y$ to $Y'$, then its boundary is $Y \sqcup Y'$ (up to orientations).

@MarcoGolla Oops, that's true.. So, what I would like to find is not a symplectic cobordism.. what I try to find is a symplectic manifold with boundary and corner $\partial M = S^1_\theta \times P \cup \mathbb{T}^3 \sqcup \mathbb{T}^3 \cup -(\mathbb{T}^3)$

@MarcoGolla In addition it's symplectomorphic to symplectization of solid tori near the ends. I don't know the exact naming of this.
